# Alterar configurações do compilador no CodeBlocks

Tags: c, c++, codeblocks

Vou participar de uma olimpíada de programação e preciso configurar o compilador, no caso o CodeBlocks, das seguintes maneiras:

C: Compilador GCC versão 8.2 ou superior - Linha de comando: gcc -lm -O2 -static -o executavel fonte.c

C++: Compilador G++ versão 8.2 ou superior - Linha de comando: g++ -std=C++11 -lm -O2 -static -o executavel fonte.cpp

Como faço essa configuração? E como posso adequar o *debugger* para essa versão do compilador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As versões do GCC e G++ são independentes do CodeBlocks que é apenas o IDE. Para ter versões atualizadas dos compiladores precisa de os instalar fazendo download dos sites originais. Em windows o [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) permite-lhe instalar um configurador (mingw-get) para instalar os vários compiladores e bibliotecas na sua máquina. Na maioria das distribuições linux o `gcc` já vem instalado, mas também consegue instalar a versão mais atual com um simples comando no terminal.

Algumas das configurações de compilação que menciona já existem nos quadros de configuração do próprio CodeBlocks, como o `-std=` para a versão.

Aceda a Settings > Compiler:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No separador Compiler Settings e sub separador Compiler Flags escolha `Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na mesma lista um pouco mais abaixo tem também opções de performance, que incluem o `-O2` que mencionou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como aparte a *flag* `-O3` da-lhe ainda mais otimização para velocidade.

Quaisquer *flags* que não existam como opção no CodeBlocks podem ser acrescentadas através do sub separador Other compiler options:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, o CodeBlocks já linka por defeito com a biblioteca `math`, tornando a *flag* `-lm` redundante, mas pode variar com base na instalação/configuração que fez.

Exemplo de compilação com as configurações mostradas nesta resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Olá, usando o CodeBlock você deve entrar

Menubar Settings->Compiler and Debugger
Selecione GNU GCC Compiler
Selecione a Toolchain executablesaba

Lá você consegue selecionar qual compilador C e C++ vai usar.

Uma dica já que você está participando de uma olimpíada é dar uma olhada nessa ferramenta da Jetbrains: https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/ . Se você for estudante consegue uma licença de um ano (eu acho)

Se estiver usando Linux, para verificar a verão basta usar **$gcc --version**